# imprimir en pantalla un array tipo unsigned char con iostream

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Tengo una aplicación de consola en C++ en Visual Studio Express 2013 con el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

void GetValores(unsigned char* c)
{
    // aquí va mucho código que asigna valores a otro puntero unsigned char llamado temp

    int i = 0;
    while (*temp != '\0') // copio los valores
    {
        c[i] = *temp;
        temp++;
        i++;
    }

    c[i] = '\0'; // le pongo el caracter nulo al final.
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned char* cadena = new unsigned char[256];
    GetValores(cadena); // todo bien, recibo mis valores como debe ser
}
```

Mi problema es que ahora quiero imprimir los valores de `cadena` en pantalla.
He intentado con:

```
string str;
str.assign((char*)cadena, 256);  // los valores se copian bien
cout << str;
```

pero en la línea `cout << str;` el compilador me arroja el error: "ningún operador coincide con estos comandos, los tipos de operando son std::ostream<

pero cuando la cambio por:

```
std::ostream << str;
```

ahora el compilador me dice "se esperaba un identificador", y no me deja imprimir mi string.

Comment: No veo que estés incluyendo `<string>` así que no debería siquiera compilarte. ¿Se te ha olvidado añadir algo de código?

Comment: Deberías poner código mínimo que compile.

Comment: en realidad éste es sólo un fragmento de un código ma´s largo

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster por lo poco que se, se que `<iostream>` incluye la libreria `<string>`. aqui un ejemplo de lo que digo http://cpp.sh/7vvc

Comment: @bassily cierto. Eso explica por qué compila mas sigue sin ser correcto, debemos incluir las cabeceras que usamos en lugar de confiar en que otras cabeceras lo harán por nosotros ¿qué pasaría si en otra implementación de C++ `<iostream>` NO INCLUYERA `<string>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `GetValores` no debería nombrarse así, ya que *get* significa *obtener*, y en el código está asignando valores, entonces debería nombrarse `setValores`, con minúscula porque no es una estructura de datos `struct`.

No es necesario crear una función que funcione como una fábrica de `strings` en C++ porque se asignan automáticamente, así que `GetValores` quedaría descartada.

Lo único que se debe poner dentro del `main` es esto, nadie va por la vida creando `unsigned char`.

```
string str = "Hola Mundo";
cout << str << endl;
```

Como bien dice @PaperBirdMaster, por las dudas, incluye `string`, debería quedar así.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
```

Comment: mi error fue éste: olvidé incluir la librería string. D'oh!